# how to use my own form structure in agile toolkit?

Tags: atk4, agiletoolkit

in agile toolkit we only can change the form style but is it possible to change the form body and it's structure?
I want to change HTML...

something like this:

```
$form->htmlsource();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use this method to set your custom layout

https://github.com/atk4/atk4/blob/master/lib/Form/Basic.php#L413